# passing variable from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to pass a variable from a function in JavaScript to PHP that is also inside the JavaScript function.

For Example:

```
myfunction('qwerty');

<script>
myfunctionjs(x)
{
<?php echo $x?>
}
</script>
```

**note:** code above is just a sample

Comment: A better question would be "How can we write a filter for StackOverflow that prevents the same damn questions from being asked 32767 times a day?"

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  looking at sidebar list of related questions...have to wonder how everyone of them bypasses all the prompts that show up as they type the same keywords `pass variable javascript/php`

Answer (score 2):

Passing variable from javascript to php right away is not possible. You will have to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this. You have to understand the difference between server-side scripting and client-side scripting.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Read the above link and it will give you a full understanding of the process. if you have any issues let me know.

[Read more](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/passing_javascript_variables_php.php)

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample, while it expresses what you want quite clearly, should also show how impossible it is.

PHP is a server-side language whereas javascript is a client-side language. The only way for javascript to "talk" to PHP is to submit a request to the server. You can do this either through a standard HTTP-GET request or a POST request (through a form submission, or more commonly via Ajax).

Answer (score 2):

The PHP isn't inside the JavaScript function. The PHP code is executed on the server.
When the Javascript is executed, the code looks like this:

```
myfunction('qwerty');

<script>
myfunctionjs(x)
{
 alert(x);  //or whatever $x is
}
</script>
```

If you want to pass 'x' to a PHP script, you'll have to make an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have javascript telling PHP to do something inline. JavaScript runs client side, while PHP runs server side.

Instead, you need to have your javascript **send** the data to your server, and you'll have PHP do something when receiving that second request.

If you are using jQuery, have a look at the ajax method for example on how to send data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/